¿Cómo pasar coordenadas de TEXT en MYSQL a MULTIPOLYGON?
Buen Día.
Tengo una duda. Tengo una tabla de BD en MYSQL con coordenadas consecutivas en latitud y longitud en forma de texto.
EJEMPLO:
claveUT 02-001  AGUILERA    
poligono 19.47374036,-99.15901487
 19.47375297,-99.15882061
 19.47371803,-99.15796346
 19.47363169,-99.15616256
 19.4734649,-99.1544331
 19.47330417,-99.15265773
 19.47321071,-99.1526744
 19.47311725,-99.15269107
 19.4726559,-99.15277335
 19.47233728,-99.15283017
 19.47171

claveUT 02-002  ALDANA
poligono 19.47155997,-99.14857148
 19.47106207,-99.14863103
 19.47060834,-99.14866123
 19.47043154,-99.14864769
 19.47042109,-99.14858124
 19.46999401,-99.14859562
 19.4696299,-99.14866172
 19.4695321,-99.1479995
 19.46931962,-99.148596
 19.46922579,-99.14885942
 19.469209...

Pero quiero hacer el campo de las coordenadas (formato TEXT) a un dato Geoespacial (MULTIPOLYGON).

Si lo que deseas es un multipolígono, ¿cómo identificas cuántos polígonos tienes y qué coordenadas pertenecen a cada polígono?

@jachguate Porque cada polígono tiene un identificador único junto con ella las coordenadas están relacionadas con ese mismo identificador

No sé de qué hablas, en la lista no se ve ese identificador, solamente las coordenadas.

Ya se actualizo la pregunta para mayor entendimiento

Puedes aplicar algunas transformaciones al texto para formar una cadena en formato WKT (Well Known Text), que es uno de los formatos para datos geoespaciales soportados por MYSQL.
Yo he construido esta solución basada en llamadas a las siguientes funciones de strings 1:

substring() para obtener la parte de un string
relpace() para reemplazar caracteres fijos por otros. Es de notar que he usado la construcción '\n' para reemplazar los saltos de línea por las comas correspondientes.
regexp_replace para reemplazar las coincidencias de expresiones regulares 2 y así detectar los puntos de inicio de cada polígono y limpiar la cadena.
concat() para construir la cadena final.

La consulta resultante es:
select concat(
         'MULTIPOLYGON('
       , regexp_replace(
           replace(
             substring(
               regexp_replace(
                   regexp_replace(
                       replace(Coordenadas, ',', ' ')
                     , 'claveUT.*', '')
                 , 'poligono ', ')),((') from 5)
           , '\n', ',')
         , ',+\\)', ')')
       , ')))') Poligono
  from MiTabla;

Asumo que la tabla se llama MiTabla y el campo se llama Coordenadas.
Con tus datos de ejemplo, luego de limpiarlos quitando los errores 3 dónde había líneas solo con una coordenada o puntos de más, esto produce la salida:
MULTIPOLYGON(((19.47374036 -99.15901487, 19.47375297 -99.15882061, 19.47371803 -99.15796346, 19.47363169 -99.15616256, 19.4734649 -99.1544331, 19.47330417 -99.15265773, 19.47321071 -99.1526744, 19.47311725 -99.15269107, 19.4726559 -99.15277335, 19.47233728 -99.15283017)),((19.47155997 -99.14857148, 19.47106207 -99.14863103, 19.47060834 -99.14866123, 19.47043154 -99.14864769, 19.47042109 -99.14858124, 19.46999401 -99.14859562, 19.4696299 -99.14866172, 19.4695321 -99.1479995, 19.46931962 -99.148596, 19.46922579 -99.14885942)))

fiddle
Una vez tienes este texto, podrías llamar a la función ST_GeomFromText() para tener el dato en formato binario.
No tengo MySQL a mano para probarlo, es probable que tengas todavía que envolver el multipolígono en GEOMETRY(), que lo puedes agregar fácilmente en los parámetros de la llamada a concat().

1: La sentencia puede parecer intimidante al inicio, pero no es más que una secuencia anidada de llamadas a las funciones del listado. Para comprender al 100% su funcionamiento, puedes quitar todas y dejar solo la última (la más interna, que es replace(Coordenadas..., y a partir de allí ir agregando las llamadas más externas una a una.
Verás como cada una va limpiando y construyendo la solución paso a paso, a partir del resultado de la llamada a la función más interna.  La suma de todos estos pasos da como resultado la solución.
2: Si no tienes experiencia con expresiones regulares, lee la documentación sobre ellas. Puedes también utilizar sitios como regex101 para probarlas, colocando el resultado de la llamada a la función más interna como test string y el segundo parámetro como regular expresion, el sitio te explica el funcionamiento de esa expresión en particular y te muestra gráficamente las coincidencias que se dan en el texto, que serán sustituidas en mySQL por el string que se pasa como tercer parámetro. Si haces esto, debes recordar sustituir todas las dobles barras invertidas por una sola, es decir \\ cambia a \ ya en la expresión regular. La documentación te explica por qué ocurre esto.
3: Es importante que los datos estén limpios. Esta es responsabilidad de los  usuarios. Puedes agregar validaciones en el ingreso de datos para que no ingresen errores como los que se ven en el texto de ejemplo, pues, en mi opinión, resulta demasiado caro escribir código que corrija todos los posibles errores que puedan cometer.
